# password recovery error in joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, password-recovery

Reset password failed: A Super Administrator can't request a password reminder. Please contact another Super Administrator or use an alternative method.

the above error message appeared when i tried to reset a normal user password in the frontend page. I confirmed that the user isn't a super admin or admin for my joomla 1.7 site, the user is just a normal register user.

thx in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user has the same e-mail address as a super administrator. That's the only explanation I can see.

Comment: the problem solved suddenly without any reason. i guess one of the main reasons would be the hosting issue